# Nested redux state updates triggers render on each siblings

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, lifecycle

Description: I am trying to update a state of a nested object. While updating the nested object, I see its sibling component's render method is also being called.

Expected behavior: From all the articles I have been through, it specifies if I return a new object with only updated nested object, react is smart enough to render only updated object.

Example:

reducer.tsx

```
// imports

const initialState = {
  firstLevel: {
    secondLevel: {
      jobLevel: {
        id: 'L52';
      },
      expectedSalary: {
        amount: '100000';
      }
    }
  }
}

export interface State {
  firstLevel: {
    secondLevel: {
      jobLevel: {
        id: string;
      },
      expectedSalary: {
        amount: string;
      }
    }
  }
}

export const mainState = (state: State = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'NESTED_UPDATE':
      return {
        ...state,
        firstLevel : {
          secondLevel: {
            ...state.firstLevel.secondLevel,
            expectedSalary: {
              amount: '120000'
            }
          }
        }
      }
  }

}
```

So in the above redux state, I am not mutating state, to start with. I am returning new object which has change in > `firstLevel.secondLevel.expectedSalary` object. While `firstLevel.secondLevel.jobLevel` object is not changed.

Components:

Main.tsx

```
// imports
class MainSection extends Component<> {
  // constructor and more logic

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <JobLevel {...props.firstLevel.secondLevel} />
      </div>
      <div>
        <ExpectedSalary 
          {...props.firstLevel.secondLevel}
          updateSecondLevel={this.props.updatedSecondLevel} //I know its included in props, for readability
        />
      </div>
  }
}

export default MainSection;
```

MainContainer.jsx

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {SplitActions, CreateRuleState} from '../types';
import RuleSplitSection from '../components/RuleSplitSection';
import Actions from '../actions/RuleDrawerActions';
import {calculateSplitRuleLineWidth} from '../utils/RuleUtil';

export const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return state;
};

export const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        updateSecondLevel: () => dispatch(Actions.updateSecondLevel())
    };
};

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Main as any);
```

Subcomponents:
JobLevel.jsx

```
class JobLevel extends Component<> {
  // constructor and more logic

  render() {
    return (
      // debug point 1
      <div>
        // assume TextField is another redux util component which takes some props as below.
        <TextField
          value={this.props.jobLevel}
          disabled // read only
        />
      </div>
  }
}
```

ExpectedSalary.jsx

```
class ExpectedSalary extends Component<> {
  // constructor and more logic

  updateExpectedSalarySecondLevel = evt => {
    const expectedSalaryObj = {amount: evt.target.value}
    this.props.updateSecondLevel('expectedSalary', expectedSalaryObj);
  } 


  render() {
    return (
      // debug point 2 
      <div>
        // assume TextField is another redux util component which takes some props as below.
        <TextField 
          onChange={this.updateExpectedSalarySecondLevel}
          value={this.props.expectedSalary}
        />
      </div>
  }
}
```

Scenario: In above case, when I type anything in ExpectedSalary Textfield, I am hardcoding the value to '120000' for now. My understanding was when I updated ExpectedSalary `subobject`, react is smart enough to just re-render ExpectedSalary sub component. But from debugging it, I am seeing that it stops at both `debug point 1 and 2`.

I was wondering why??? 
Now to avoid re-rendering of JobLevel I need to use `shouldComponentUpdate` and check deep copy  like below:

```
    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
        return this.props.jobLevel.id !== nextProps.jobLevel.id;
    }
```

So my questions would be:
 1. Going inside render method of JobLevel is part of react life-cycle?
 2. If so, do I need to avoid it? Is it expensive process?

Let me know is `comments` if more code reference is required. I have excluded `Actions` file from the code simple from boredom of typing here.

Comment: My guess is `mainState` in reducer is changing the object inside first and second level thus you may be facing this issue, you can validate that in React devtools Profile tab which can tell you why a particular component re-rendered

Answer (score 1):

By default react re-renders all components on every re-render. You need to mark a component as `Pure` and have stable props, or implement `componentDidUpdate` as you've done to avoid a re-render. `react-redux` does this for `connect`ed components.

In your case there are couple of things necessary to avoid re-rendering `JobLevel`. The first is to extend `PureComponent` instead of `Component` and the second is to only pass in the necessary props at the call site.

```
import {PureComponent} from 'react';

class JobLevel extends PureComponent<> {
  // constructor and more logic
  ...
}
```

And right now when you're rendering `JobLevel` you are spreading all of `...props.firstLevel.secondLevel` which includes the `expectedSalary` key which is changing. You will need to only pass the required, stable props:

`<JobLevel jobLevel={props.firstLevel.secondLevel.jobLevel} />`

Otherwise you are essentially doing

```
<JobLevel
  jobLevel={props.firstLevel.secondLevel.jobLevel}
  expectedSalary={props.firstLevel.secondLevel.expectedSalary}
/>
```

so since the `expectedSalary` prop is changing, the component will be re-rendered even if `JobLevel` is marked Pure. React cannot introspect your render code to know which props are being used or not - it does a shallow comparison across all props that are passed to decide if a `PureComponent` needs to be re-rendered.

Comment: Thats very detailed answer. Thank you!! So it would be 2 more steps, first of all make it pure and then make sure to pass only related props. Basically whatever i am passing would be root to the component and shallow check would be done on that. So if jobLevel is the root component, shallow check would caught it if its a `pure` function.

Comment: yes, exactly, for pure components each prop is checked against the incoming value (so a shallow comparison between `this.props` and `nextProps` in `shouldComponentUpdate`) to decide if a re-render is necessary.